# Are there actually 4 types of Product Topologies?

Tags: general-topology

We learned about the Product Topology recently in class. So for $X,Y$ topological spaces, then we define $X\times{Y}$ to be the product topology. From what I understand, for $U\subset{X}$ and $V\subset{Y}$, we have that $U\times{V}\subset{X\times{Y}}$ is open iff both $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$ and $Y$, respectively. My question is that can we similarly define 3 more product topologies in the following way:

(1) We call an open set in $X\times{Y}$ open if it is of the form $U\times{V}$, where $U$ is closed in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.

(2) We call an open set in $X\times{Y}$ open if it is of the form $U\times{V}$, where $U$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is closed in $Y$.

(3) We call an open set in $X\times{Y}$ open if it is of the form $U\times{V}$, where $U$ is closed in $X$ and $V$ is closed in $Y$.

I get that we need to be more specific here because we need to make sure that we have unions and intersections and stuff. So I was thinking that we could take the basis for the product topologies (1) and (2) above by considering a basis for the open sets and a basis for the closed sets. The basis for the open sets would be the regular basis on $X$ or $Y$ and the basis for the closed set would be the complement of each of the basis elements in $X$ or $Y$. Then if we take all things of the form $B_1\times{B_2}$, where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are basis sets, and put them in our topology, then does this work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant, but it seems like (1), (2) and (3) are not (in general) topologies, because an arbitrary union of closed sets is not necessarily a closed set.

Comment: For something to be "product topology", it must make projections continuous (it is the coarsest topology to do this).

Answer (score 4):

It should be very easy to show, that the 3 topologies you defined do not satisfy the axioms of a topology in general (i.e. let $X=Y=\Bbb R$ with the standard topology). For any set $X$, any subset of $2^{X}$ (the power set of $X$) defines a basis for a topology. There a lot of different topologies on a given set. The reason the one is given as the "product topology", is that is the coarsest topology that satisfies the universal property of a product.

**Universal Property for Product Topology:** For any continuous maps $h:Z\rightarrow X$, $g:Z\rightarrow Y$, there exists a unique map $f:Z\rightarrow X\times Y$ with $\pi_1 \circ f=h$ and $\pi_2 \circ f=g$ (where $\pi_1$ is the projection onto $X$ and $\pi_2$ is the projection onto $Y$).

c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Products